# (WPF | Visual Studio | XDG0010 ) Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral"

Tags: c#, wpf

Короче, решил установить в свой проект Material Design. Все сделал как в гайде, установил пакеты в nuget, добавил следующие строки в app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="FMods2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FMods2;assembly=FMods2"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

И также в MainWindow.xaml добавил строку:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
```

Все по сути должно работать, но неожиданно пишется ошибка на все 4 строки отсылок к зависимостям в app.xaml

Ошибка  XDG0010 Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, Culture=neutral" либо одну из их зависимостей.

Ошибка  XDG0010 Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MaterialDesignColors, Culture=neutral" либо одну из их зависимостей.

И так происходит в каждом новом создаваемом проекте, уже переустанавливал VS(стоит VS2022 новой версии), но ничего не помогает. Пытаясь добавить любой из обьектов MaterialDesign(шаблонов кнопок и тд) также выдает ошибку и они просто не отображаются. Использую .Net framework 7.6.2

Comment: Проект пересоберите. XAML обновляет данные о классах только после успешного билда проекта.

Comment: Net framework 7.6.2 не существует. Быть может 4.6.2? Так он устарел и возможно несовместим с этой библиотекой.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я перепутал весии, Net framework 4.7.2, проблема решилась просто ребилдом проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Просто поменял версию тем на 3.2.0 и все работает